# Problem with Selenium Tests in Angular (isStable always false)

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

In my project we have Automated Tests in Selenium. Our application using AngularJS but we're rewriting to Angular 9 using [Hybrid Approach](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#upgrading-with-ngupgrade). The problem is that those tests doesn't work because the method `getAllAngularTestabilities()[0].whenStable()` is never [run callback](https://angular.io/api/core/Testability#whenstable) to inform Selenium that Angular finished underhood work.

Also when I run [method](https://angular.io/api/core/Testability#isStable) `getAllAngularTestabilities()[0].isStable()` then is always returnig false.

It's weird because property isStable is true, also microTasks and macroTask are empty.

[image]

But in fact somewhere deeper there is some loop that not allowing to Stable application, I was able to find this out thanks to answer from @Stanislav Berkov [How to track which async tasks protractor is waiting on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627074/how-to-track-which-async-tasks-protractor-is-waiting-on/57854350#57854350)

And apparently there is MacroTask from oidc-client, probably for refreshing token which is triggered every few minutes
[image]

And I've no idea how can I solve this. Maybe I could exclude the whole package somehow from zone.js, but I don't know how can I do this.

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: We are having the same issue. Did you ever got it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

`isStable` will not emit `true` if you have pending macrotasks (like `setTimeout` or `setInterval`). Be sur to not have these in the bootstrapping process of yout app.